# JDBC/Hibernate to transform the batches into multi-insert statements

Tags: sql-server, oracle, hibernate, jdbc, hsqldb

I want to **save/update** list of objects in a way that there should be maximum of **4 SQL operation/query** on the database.

> 2 insert query for new records for two different tables.
>
> 2 update query for update records of two different tables.

Is it possible in Hibernate for HSQL, MSQL, Oracle, MYSQL

By searching around this I have come across the following solution for insert with MySQL.

---

Set following property for hibernate session factory configuration.

***hibernate.jdbc.batch_size***

And use following connection URL

```
jdbc\:mysql\://localhost\:3306/opshub?rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

It generates single insert query

```
insert into test values (1,"abc"),(2,"xyz");
```

Required this for **HSQL, MSSQL, ORACLE**

I have java Object representing tables like below.

```
class UserDetails{

int id;
String userName;

OneToMany
List<UserAssociation> association;

}

class UserAssociation{

ManyToOne
UserDetails user;
int systemId;
int lastSeenTime;

}
```

I will be having following records for insert/update

```
 List<UserDetails> inserts (with List<UserAssociation> association);
 List<UserAssociation> inserts and update for UserDetails
 
 List<UserDetails> updates
 List<UserAssociation> updats
```

Requirement is to dumb this data in DB with max of 4 queries with Hibernate and all DB server like SQL-SERVER, MySQL, ORACLE, HSQL

Comment: You need to add the Java objects to your question.

Comment: Made changes. Please let me know if anything else is required. Thanks